# Need help for GKE ingress with terraform for n8n deployment

Tags: terraform, google-kubernetes-engine, nginx-ingress, gke-networking, n8n

I try to deploy [n8n](https://n8n.io) with its helm chart (https://github.com/8gears/n8n-helm-chart) to a GKE cluster.
The problem I now face is when I set up the ingress to point to the application it loses the session constantly. I already found out that it has to be related to the ingress because when I access the pod directly everything works fine.

I try now to set up session affinity on the ingress, but I can't find any resource on how I can do this with terraform. My second option would be to set up an Nginx ingress but I have no experience how to do this. I hope someone can help me to find this out or point me to a better solution for the ingress. Thanks!

This is my terraform config for n8n:

```
resource "google_compute_managed_ssl_certificate" "n8n_ssl" {
  name = "${var.release_name}-ssl"
  managed {
    domains = ["n8n.${var.host}"]
  }
}
resource "helm_release" "n8n" {
  count           = 1
  depends_on      = [kubernetes_namespace.n8n, google_sql_database.n8n, google_sql_user.n8n, google_compute_managed_ssl_certificate.n8n_ssl]
  repository      = "https://8gears.container-registry.com/chartrepo/library"
  chart           = "n8n"
  version         = var.helm_version
  name            = var.release_name
  namespace       = var.namespace
  recreate_pods   = true
  values = [
    "${file("n8n_values.yaml")}"
  ]
  set_sensitive {
    name  = "n8n.encryption_key"
    value = var.n8n_encryption_key
  }
  set {
    name  = "config.database.postgresdb.host"
    value = data.terraform_remote_state.cluster.outputs.database_connection
  }
  set {
    name  = "config.database.postgresdb.user"
    value = var.db_username
  }
  set_sensitive {
    name  = "secret.database.postgresdb.password"
    value = var.db_password
  }
  set {
    name  = "config.security.basicAuth.user"
    value = var.username
  }
  set_sensitive {
    name  = "config.security.basicAuth.password"
    value = var.password
  }
}

resource "kubernetes_ingress" "n8n_ingress" {
  wait_for_load_balancer = true
  depends_on = [google_compute_managed_ssl_certificate.n8n_ssl]
  metadata {
    name = "${var.release_name}-ingress"
    namespace = helm_release.n8n[0].namespace
    annotations = {
      "ingress.kubernetes.io/compress-enable"         = "false",
      "ingress.gcp.kubernetes.io/pre-shared-cert"     = google_compute_managed_ssl_certificate.n8n_ssl.name
    }
  }
  spec {
    backend {
      service_name = helm_release.n8n[0].name
      service_port = 80
    }
  }
}
```

and my n8n_values.yml:

```yaml
config:
  port: 5678
  generic:
    timezone: Europe/London
  database:
    type: postgresdb
  security:
    basicAuth:
      active: true

secret:
  database:
    postgresdb:
      password: ""

extraEnv:
  VUE_APP_URL_BASE_API: https://n8n.***/
  WEBHOOK_TUNNEL_URL: https://n8n.***/

image:
  repository: n8nio/n8n
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  tag: latest

service:
  type: ClusterIP
  port: 80
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable session affinity with GKE Ingress, you will need to create a [BackendConfig](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-features#associating_backendconfig_with_your_ingress) resource.  GKE Ingress supports client IP or cookie-based affinity.

```
apiVersion: cloud.google.com/v1
kind: BackendConfig
metadata:
  name: my-backendconfig
spec:
  sessionAffinity:
    affinityType: "CLIENT_IP"


apiVersion: cloud.google.com/v1
kind: BackendConfig
metadata:
  name: my-backendconfig
spec:
  sessionAffinity:
    affinityType: "GENERATED_COOKIE"
    affinityCookieTtlSec: 50
```

When using terraform, I think you'd need to use the [kubernetes_manifest](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/resources/manifest) resource to deploy the BackendConfig resource.

You would then need to add the BackendConfig as an annotation  on the Service resource.  Looking at the  [service.yaml](https://github.com/8gears/n8n-helm-chart/blob/master/templates/service.yaml) provided by the helm chart, it does not appear you can add annotations via values.yaml so you'd need to modify it to support adding annotations.

Comment: Thank you very much @gari-singh the kubernetes_manifest was exactly what I needed and I completely missed it. The actual problem was that when the ingress closed the connection n8n killed the session what made the workflows fail. Hopefully, we will not have workflows that run for more than 5 min.